# Delay before update a Group Profile Picture?

Tags: microsoft-graph-teams, microsoft-graph-groups

I'm using the Microsoft Graph SDK for creating Group / Team and set up a Profile Picture.

I realize that I can't set up the Group Photo right after its creation : I have to wait a couple of minutes / hours to update it (and it works of course). Below is the common error met :

`Code: ErrorInvalidGroup. Message: The requested group [Group GUID]@[Tenant GUID] is invalid. Inner error`

Any idea on the process ? It is a "normal" bug because of a delay of "complete creation" ?

Thx for your answers.